# Postgres parameterized query with INSERT ON CONFLICT and geometry not working in PHP

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, prepared-statement, postgres-9.6

I do not know why this isn't working.  Is it something about using parameters in the query twice?  Using PHP 7.4.33, Postgres PostgreSQL 9.6.22.

Error is:

```
Warning: pg_query_params(): Query failed: ERROR:  inconsistent types deduced for parameter $2
LINE 11:                 , $2
                           ^
DETAIL:  double precision versus numeric in /home/douglass/redata/process.php on line 36
```

What could be the problem?

Here's what I did (I know lat/lon are in the row twice, once in a point, once in individual columns, but for the sake of the example, I would like to understand the error):

Created table:

```
(
  unique_id numeric,
  latitude numeric,
  longitude numeric,
  coordinates geometry(Point,4326)
);
```

Ran PHP:

```
    pg_query_params($connection, "
INSERT INTO test_table5
                (
                unique_id 
                , latitude
                , longitude
                , coordinates )
        VALUES (
        $1
                , $2
                , $3
                ,  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( $3, $2), 4326) )
        ON CONFLICT
                (unique_id)
        DO UPDATE SET
                latitude = $2
                , longitude = $3
                , coordinates =  ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint( $3, $2), 4326)",
                     [
                        50113947,
                        35.76673,
                        -78.36914
                     ]);
```

Comment: Offtopic: are you sure about PostgreSQL 9.6.22? That version is EOL for several years. Upgrade to at least version 15

Comment: @FrankHeikens This is my first time using PostgreSQL.  That's what shows up in phpPgAdmin.  I'll ask my hosting service about upgrading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres has a richer and stricter type system than PHP, so when you pass in any value, a decision needs to be made about what type it should be. Most of the time, you don't need to think about this, because Postgres *deduces* the correct type from the context where the value is used.

That goes some way to explaining this message:

> inconsistent types deduced for parameter $2

Because you've used `$2` in two different places, there are two different contexts which Postgres can use to deduce the right type; the problem is, it's come up with two different answers.

> DETAIL:  double precision versus numeric

We can see the context where `numeric` is the best choice: you have declared `latitude numeric` in your table, and then inserted `$2` into that column.

That leaves `ST_MakePoint( $3, $2)`. Looking up [a manual page for the function](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/ST_MakePoint.html) confirms that its arguments are of type `double precision`.

To resolve the ambiguity, you can add *casts* to one or both contexts: `CAST($2 AS numeric)` for the table column and/or `ST_MakePoint(CAST($3 AS float), CAST($2 AS float))` (`float` is an alias for `double precision`).

Comment: Ok, interesting. I thought it would cast separately based on each time it is used, similar to how it would if I typed it in manually each time.  Apparently I am too new to upvote the question, but thanks, that worked.

Comment: @developer981 I think the logic is a bit like if you were defining the query as a function, with $2 as one of the parameters; you would have to declare the parameter with some particular type. Only once the parameter is passed in could you then cast it to other types.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Postgres complaining about `double precision versus numeric`. Given that your column is `numeric` the PHP bound column must be `double precision`.  What happens when you use an explicit cast in SQL?

```
$2::numeric
```

Looking at the [PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php) there is no representation of Postgres' `numeric` type in PDO.